# Inversion of the Burrows Wheelers Transform

Tags: linear-algebra, signal-processing, data-analysis

The "Burrows-Wheeler Transform" in signal processing is a transformation which is used in for instance data compression and pattern recognition.

It can be described in mathematical terms as:

Start with a column vector $\bf v$.

1. Build the circulant matrix $\bf C_v$ which has ${\bf v}^t$ as it's first row and all subsequent rows are all possible circular shifts.
2. Perform a lexical sort on the rows ( series of row operations ).
3. Store the last column together with the index for the first (or last) element of the initial sequence. Let us call it $\bf b$.

Is it reasonable that there would exist a permutation matrix $\bf P$ which we can find with the information above, such that we can determine the initial $\bf v$ as a polynomial ${\bf v} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \bf P^k {\bf b}$?

Comment: Polynomials are off-topic here: the entries of $\mathbf{v}$ are not numbers or anything that can be added and subtracted a-priori.

Comment: Since $\bf P$ is assumed to be a permutation matrix, they don't have to be numbers, since any permutation of a permutation is a permutation.

Comment: Yes I missed something important. Will try and re-formulate it.

Comment: Not sure if I get the question right, but the BWT is widely used in data compression, which implies that there exists an inverse transformation. It basically relies on the fact that you can deduce the columns adjacent to $b$, and then use them to deduce their neighbors.

Comment: Yes I know BWT is so popular,  sorry I've been busy on other things for a while. Of course there exists an inverse transform, I was just curious after reading this beginners course in group theory a while ago if it was possible to represent in a particular context with permutation matrices. I did find that something similar to the question is possible and kind of straight forward to do, but then I lost my source to some computer treasure goblin. Can reproduce it from memory if I'm given an hour or two. However I never found any fast way to re-make that formalism for the forward-transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say basically no.  $|{\bf v}| = |{\bf b}|$.  If we assume all elements of $\mathbf{v}$ are positive, then $\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n} {\bf P}^k {\bf b}\right| > |{\bf v}|$ for $n > 0$.

Comment: Yes I think you are right. The formulation in the question is wrong. It should not be a sum. I realized this after writing the question, but then other things got in the way.

Comment: Since you have already answered I can not change the question, but if you look at my answer below, if we reformulate the sum a bit, we can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

As the question stands, I do not think such a sum equality to be possible, see for instance NovaDenizens answer above.

It is possible to create a permutation matrix $\bf P$ such that *the last element* of $\bf P^kb$ is the $k$:th position of the inverse transform. I.e. we build a vector $\bf v$ such that ${\bf v}_k = ({\bf P^kb})_{end}$. So in some sense this $\bf P$ could be viewed as a generating element for the inverse-transformed string. Since ${\bf P^{k+1}b} = \bf{P (P^k b)}$, we can store the vector ${\bf P^k b}$ and so we just have to multiply to the left with $\bf P$ once for every new letter.

---

1. First sort the vector b and note the order of the sorting.
2. The rows position will just be the order of this sorting.

Assuming aIn is the encoded string, the following Matlab / Octave code explains:

> [~,i_] = sort(aIn);
>
> P = sparse(i_,1:numel(i_),ones(numel(i_,1)));

---

But we can of course also produce and store powers of $\bf P$. This could be beneficial if we have multi-core processing. Imagine having ${\bf v}_1$ through ${\bf v}_8$ and ${\bf P}^8$ stored. Since permutation matrices remain permutation matrices with multiplication, then 8 independent processes could generate separate parts of our string, and they would also be guaranteed to run equally fast.

---

So if we reformulate the question to

"Is it possible to find a permutation matrix $\bf P$ such that if

1. $\bf C$ is forward rotation 1 step ( generating element of the cyclic group: ${\bf C} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
   0&1\\
   {\bf I}&0
   \end{array}\right]$),
2. $\bf D$ is the diagonal matrix with 1 lower right corner

then we can recover the original message:
$$\sum {\bf C}^k{\bf DP}^k{\bf b} = {\bf v}$$

Comment: Sorry if it is a bit short and cryptic. Will expand if someone wants me to, but have to go to the store before it closes.